# RAM and memory addressing

Tags: memory

I am studying for an exam and I am bit lost on this question

```
A computer system has a RAM containing 64k bytes, each of which needs its own distinct
address.  Moreover it has 4 peripherals and they each require 2^4 distinct addresses
in order to interface properly. 

a) How many distinct addresses in total are necessary in this system? Write the total 
   number.
```

for this question i got 65600

```
b) Place the number of addresses just computer between the appropriate poweres of two
   in the expression on the left, by writing the correct exponent.(example: if your 
   answer is 18 you would put 2^<18<2^5.)
```

this one i had 2^16 < 65600 < 2^17

```
c)How many lines does an address bus for this system rquire, given that it must
  be able to carry all the needed values for the address?
```

and I am lost on this question.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I hope I posted this with the right tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For c), you can just write 17. From b), you know the address needs strictly more than 16 bits, and less than 17 bits. So obviously, 16 address lines are not enough, and 17 is the minimum that can hold all address values (though it can represent more address values than you need).